# Jpa, Seam updating entity

Tags: java, jpa, seam

I've got a Stateful Session bean where I create a object (in this case a user object) and saving it in my db. Now I just want so update this entry which doesn't work - a `NullPointerException`is thrown instead. What is my fault here?

Bean

```
@Stateful
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Name("Userdata")
public class UserdataBean implements Userdata {

    @Logger
    private Log log;

    @In(create = true)
    private Renderer renderer;

    @In
    private IdentityManager identityManager;

    @In
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @In
    StatusMessages statusMessages;

    @Out(required = false)
    @In(required = false)
    private User user;

    private int registerType = -1;

    private int loggedIn = 0;

    @Destroy
    @Remove
    public void destroy() {
    }

    public String next() {
        DLdapIdentityStore identityStore = (DLdapIdentityStore) identityManager.getIdentityStore();
        if (loggedIn == 1) {
            if (registerType == 2) {
                entityManager.merge(getUser());
                entityManager.flush();
            } else {
                identityStore.createOrUpdateUser(getUser(), false);
            }
        } else {
            if (registerType == 1) {

                if (!identityStore.createOrUpdateUser(getUser(), true)) {
                    log.error("User cannot be generated", null);
                    statusMessages.add(Severity.ERROR, "Benutzer konnte nicht erstellt werden", null);
                    return null;
                } else {
                    log.info("User created successfully: " + getUser().getUserId(), null);
                    sendMailForUser();
                }

            } else if (registerType == 0) {
                User userFromLdap = identityStore.getProductFinderUser(user);
                if (userFromLdap == null) {
                    statusMessages.add(Severity.ERROR, "Benutzername oder Passwort falsch", null);
                    return null;
                } else {
                    user = userFromLdap;
                }

            } else if (registerType == 2) {
                getUser().setUserId(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                entityManager.persist(getUser());
            }
            loggedIn = 1;
        }

        return "wf-confirm";
    }
```

I've tried this approach too

```
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, getUser().getUserId());
                user = getUser();
                entityManager.flush();
```

Exception

```
   12:06:53,319 ERROR [application] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.process(RewriteFilter.java:98)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:57)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:87)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:130)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatefulInstanceInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.localInvoke(StatefulContainer.java:206)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulLocalProxy.invoke(StatefulLocalProxy.java:119)
    at $Proxy153.next(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor$1.proceed(ClientSideInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.ejb.RemoveInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RemoveInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor.invoke(ClientSideInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_15.next(Object_$$_javassist_seam_15.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.validator.AssertTrueValidator.isValid(AssertTrueValidator.java:15)
    at org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.getInvalidValues(ClassValidator.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.getInvalidValues(ClassValidator.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.validator.event.ValidateEventListener.validate(ValidateEventListener.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.validator.event.ValidateEventListener.onPreUpdate(ValidateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:296)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManager.flush(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(EntityManagerInvocationHandler.java:46)
    at $Proxy154.flush(Unknown Source)
    at de.ac.d.p.workflow.UserdataBean.next(UserdataBean.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.EJBInvocationContext.proceed(EJBInvocationContext.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerProxyInterceptor.aroundInvoke(EntityManagerProxyInterceptor.java:29)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernateSessionProxyInterceptor.aroundInvoke(HibernateSessionProxyInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:118)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.ExtendedPersistenceContextPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ExtendedPersistenceContextPropagationInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
    ... 98 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code generally looks OK, the fault is most probably somewhere else (configuration or other code)
from the stack trace I can see that there is a NPE during hibernate entity validation, caused on a call at line 62 of your UserdataBean (most probably the merge method call).
You should see what operation is done at that line. Most probably one of the composed entities or a property(of User) is null while it should not be.

Comment: You're right vstoyanov. I'm using Hibernate validation and the annonated field is a transient field. Seam usues the AssertTrue annonation for validation of a checkbox, anyways: Insert isn't problem but on a merge it seems like the validation is taken on the transient field too, this effect causes the exception here.

Comment: Removing the transient annonation resolves the problem, not really clean but its ok for me this way.

Comment: I think it is because of the flaw in HTML/HTTP concerning checkboxes - in Spring MVC it is worked around by adding a second hidden field when the checkbox is not selected (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-checkboxtag). Depending on which framework you use for UI there must be a better solution. Another way of solving this could involve using @PreUpdate/PrePersist JPA annotations, but that would be solving UI logic issue in the backend...